# 'mousemove' only fires once in mobile app

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mouseevent

I am creating a phonegap app. In my app I will have a not draggable Google Maps. 
In the browser, `mousemove` event fire continuously while I move the mouse around over the map.
I expected  the same behavior in my mobile phone, but the `mousemove` only fire once.

This is my main.js file

```
var app = new function () {
    return {
        initialize: function () {
            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.5403, -74.5463),
                zoom: 4,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                draggable: false,
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'mousemove', function (event) {
                console.log('move');
            });

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'mousedown', function (event) {
                console.log('down', event);
            });
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'mouseup', function (event) {
                console.log('up', event);
            });
        }
    }
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', app.initialize);
```

This is my index.html file

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        #map-canvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: #CCC;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Could anyone take a look and help my get all the `mousemove` events? I tried `touchmove` but I could not make it work with Google Maps.

Comment: have you tried to use the drag events?

Comment: The drag events are not fired because my map is not draggable.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fire the event constantly adding the code

```
function move(event) {
    console.log('touchmove', event);
    event.preventDefault();
}

document.getElementById('map-canvas').addEventListener('touchmove', move, false);
```